# Firestore Android Join Collections

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have a question concerning Cloud Firestore:

I have a collection groups, which just holds the group informations (name, found date etc) and a `group_members` collection, which has basically two fields (`group_id` and `user_id`)

Now I need to get all groups a user is member of. Currently, I just go through the `group_members` collection and check whether the `user_id` matches with the current logged in user. If so, I store the `group_id` in a list. Afterwards, I simply download all the group using their group_id from my list.

I feel like there is a better solution, but I was not able to find one. Would be nice if someone could share tips or a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now I need to get all groups a user is member of.

To achieve this, I recommend you to use a database structure that looks like this:

```
Firestore-root
   |
   --- group_members (collection)
         |
         --- uid (document)
              |
              --- user_groups (map)
                    |
                    --- group_id: true
                    |
                    --- group_id: true
```

To actually query this structure, please use the following lines of code:

For Android:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
DocumentReference uidRef = rootRef.collection("group_members").document(uid);
uidRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(/* ... */);
```

For Kotlin:

```
val rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
val uidRef = rootRef.collection("group_members").document(uid)
uidRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(/* ... */)
```

In the end just simply iterate over the `user_groups` map and get all groups the user is member of.